# Xcode - how to display image from url

Tags: xcode

I am able to display image from the sources, but was wondering how to display image from the URL link:

```
ccell.avatarImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"home_new.png"];
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this outside of the class scope:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImageView {
    func loadurl(url: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then add this to wherever you're trying to load your image:

```
let urlYourURL = URL (string: @"home_new.png")

avatarImageView.loadurl(url: urlYourURL!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the image as data from URL using NSURLConnection and use below code

```
let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView.init(image: UIImage.init(data: **data**, scale: 1.0));
```

Comment: i am not using swift